# read plist string in applescript

Tags: string, variables, applescript, plist

I just started tinkering with applescript. Please have some patience with a total beginner... This should be pretty basic but all solutions I have found so far where way too complex to work with.

My user.plist file looks like this

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>rasp</key>
            <string>username</string>
            <key>192.168.178.203</key>
            <string>ip</string>
            <key>nhnhnh3</key>
            <string>password</string>
    </array>
</plist>
```

I would like to read those strings into an applescript.
Where it says "insert_pw_here", I would like to read and insert the pw-string from user.plist in this script

```
do shell script "pmset displaysleep 15" password "insert_pw_here" with administrator priviliges
```

Basically, instead of putting passwords, usernames etc. directly into the applescripts, I am planning on creating one .plist-file from which all applescripts can gather the needed information. So that if I change anything I won't have to change several scripts. This should be very simple to do but I can't figure it out (once again: just started working with AS).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you execute the do shell script with administrator privileges, you are effectively sudoing the pmset command, so no password is needed.

Secondly, please consider the load script, and store script commands from standard addition, that way, you can have your properties in a script object instead, which is well, far more easy to program. You can also read about script objects in the AppleScript Language guide. I am sorry that there isn't a way to overcome the problems with property list files, from applescript, but I think an app/program named plist buddy, can manage to store/retrieve plist values for you. You can even use the plutil command, and convert the plist to xml first, and then use XQuery to return the values.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am system admin on this mac, however, when I remove the password line, I will be prompted to enter my pw when starting the script.

I do not necessarily need to read a plist-file. As long as I can read _any_ file that contains username, passwort and IP, I will be fine. I thought it had to be a plist file, that is why I asked for this.

Comment: I quote the manual for pmset "pmset must be run as root in order to modify any settings.", so, there isn't any user password you have to enter there really, it is your admin password, or the root accounts password. And, maybe that doesn't work, because you haven't enabled your admin account as root? I think google is your friend on that matter. I don't fully understand the problem.

Comment: I see. It doesn't really matter, though. I am still planning on implementing reading a few variables from a file - from what I know, an xml will be my best choice. I googled that but it seems like there is no example for that because what I want is too simple. All the things I have found are much more complex and I cannot modify those to fit my needs. Or is it not possible to simply read three or four variables (username, password, ip, specific file location, for example) from an xml file and use them within the applescript? Thanks :)

Comment: Hello. There are Xquery, and other XML tutorials over at w3schools.com, you may find useful. The command line tool plutil, which at least came withe the developer tools, lets you convert a plist file into an xml file. And you really shouldn't store passwords in XML files, or text files for that matter. If it is really about being able to store some objects in a file, then I'd declare a script object, that I would store, and load. The next best thing, is to for instance Grep a text file, from a do shell script, and then extract the values from the returned paragraphs of a do shell script.

Comment: Actually, PlistBuddy that comes with the Xcode developert tools that is free, is your best option. There are a lot of googable examples of usage. You need to sign up for a developer account in order to get Xcode, but look through the downloads page, and see if you just download commandline tools, and if the commandline tools contains PlistBuddy, should you have qualms for downloading the whole thing.